# Given world position and normalized world space compute 2D canvas location

Tags: c#, wpf, vector

I am trying to create a F1 2021 Radar like shown in the repository here: https://github.com/ryry6/f1-radar-releases

Or in the image here
[image: here]

I have computed the delta X and Z coordinates to each of the cars, however I am struggling to get the cars to appear as intended on a 2D Canvas (C#, WPF).

The following is the data provided by the game:

```
public float m_worldPositionX;           // World space X position
public float m_worldPositionY;           // World space Y position
public float m_worldPositionZ;           // World space Z position
public float m_worldVelocityX;           // Velocity in world space X
public float m_worldVelocityY;           // Velocity in world space Y
public float m_worldVelocityZ;           // Velocity in world space Z
public short m_worldForwardDirX;         // World space forward X direction (normalised)
public short m_worldForwardDirY;         // World space forward Y direction (normalised)
public short m_worldForwardDirZ;         // World space forward Z direction (normalised)
public short m_worldRightDirX;           // World space right X direction (normalised)
public short m_worldRightDirY;           // World space right Y direction (normalised)
public short m_worldRightDirZ;           // World space right Z direction (normalised)
public float m_gForceLateral;            // Lateral G-Force component
public float m_gForceLongitudinal;       // Longitudinal G-Force component
public float m_gForceVertical;           // Vertical G-Force component
public float m_yaw;                      // Yaw angle in radians
public float m_pitch;                    // Pitch angle in radians
public float m_roll;                     // Roll angle in radians
```

The following is the code I am unsure about...

```
var deltaX = PlayerCar.m_worldPositionX - OtherCar.m_worldPositionX;
var deltaZ = PlayerCar.m_worldPositionZ - OtherCar.m_worldPositionZ;
var deltaYawRad = PlayerCar.m_yaw - OtherCar.m_yaw;
// Convert from RAD to DEG
double deltaYaw = (180 / Math.PI) * deltaYawRad;

// This is the part I need help with
var moveUp = deltaZ * worldRightDirZ + deltaX * worldForwardDirX;
var moveLeft = deltaX * worldRightDirX + deltaZ * worldForwardDirZ;

// Set the rectangle to a position on the canvas and scale it accordingly
Canvas.SetTop(rec, RadarModel.PlayerCarTop + moveUp * RadarModel.Scale);
Canvas.SetLeft(rec, RadarModel.PlayerCarLeft + moveLeft * RadarModel.Scale);
```

Comment: I would *highly* recommend that you start using a decent vector library instead of doing all your transforms etc by hand. That should make your code much easier to read and reason about. There are plenty to chose from System.Windows.Vector, System.Numerics.Vector2, MathNet.Spatial.Euclidean.Vector2D, or write your own.

Comment: WPF is a "decent vector library" for this purpose. See System.Windows.Vector.

Comment: Good idea. Any ideas on what I would be transforming?